# Find element in collection of collection elements

Tags: java, recursion

Good time of the day!
Please tell me how to implement the following search correctly.

There are collection of elments like:

```
class Item {
    int itemId;
    List<Item> items;
}
```

How to determine exists an element with the specified `itemId` in one of the collections `items` of such elements? I understand that the recursive search method can help here, but I don't know how to implement it correctly.

Comment: How would you do it in your own words?

Comment: Please show what you have attempted.

Comment: @Sorand DFS of BFS?

Comment: I have one Item element. And I need to find out if it contains another Item element with a certain id.

Comment: @dbl, yes , it does

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a graph structure. To search such structures you should use some searching algorithms  like BFS/DFS .
Example using Deepth First Search .

```
class Item {

  private String name;
  private boolean visisted;
  private List<Item> items;

  public boolean isVisisted() {
     return visisted;
  }

  public void setVisisted(boolean visisted) {
     this.visisted = visisted;
  }

  public List<Item> getItems() {
      return items;
  }

  public void setItems(List<Item> items) {
     this.items = items;
  }

}

class DFS {

  private Stack<Item> stack;

  public DFS(Stack<Item> stack) {
    this.stack = stack;
  }

  public void dfs(List<Item> items) {
      for (Item i : items) {
          if (!i.isVisisted()) {
              i.setVisisted(true);
              dfsStack(i);
          }
      }
  }

  public void dfsStack(Item rootItem) {
       this.stack.add(rootItem);
       rootItem.setVisisted(true);

      while (!stack.isEmpty()) {
         Item actualItem = this.stack.pop();
         for (Item i : actualItem.getItems()) {
             if (!i.isVisisted()) {
                i.setVisisted(true);
                this.stack.push(i);
             }
         }
     }
  }

}
```

Comment: @Sorand did you really managed to find the particular Item that you've been searching for?

Comment: This is algorithm iterates all elements in graph , you need to add comparison condition and return element if  it matches.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
Item myItem = items.stream()
  .filter(item -> searchedId == item.getItemId())
  .findAny() // or findFirst, depending on your needs
  .orElse(null);
```

And then, you can create a method returning a boolean stating if myItem is null or not.

This method should look like

```
public boolean existsItem(int searchedId) {

    Item myItem = items.stream()
      .filter(item -> searchedId == item.getItemId())
      .findAny() // or findFirst, depending on your needs
      .orElse(null);

    return myItem != null;
    
}
```

This method must be in your class.

You should also create getters and setters for your attributes itemId and items (it's a good practice and every IDE has a way to generate them with a simple clic on a menu).

No need to be more recursive than using Item in items attribute.

Comment: Can you pls write this method? Must it be recursive?