# Filter the sublist in an object and return java 8

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I need an employee object which should have address having pin 40001 from below object .

```
    Employee eObj= new Employee(1,"abc",10001,
                    Arrays.asList(new Address("ad1","ad2","tel","40001"),new Address("ad1","ad2","tel1","40002")));
```

// need help to write below logic

```
Employee filteredEobj ={Logic}
```

//Expected response

```
new Employee(1,"abc",10001,Arrays.asList(new Address("ad1","ad2","tel","40001"));
How can we achieve this using java 8?
```

Comment: I dont get the question. You want a new employee which has the same data but only one address with 40001? Or just the address with 40001? Can you elaborate on how exactly the resulting Employee should look like? Also, for clarification, could you show an approach using traditional loops? Will be much easier for us to convert then.

Comment: yes your understanding is right

Comment: Looks like: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63415198/find-element-in-collection-of-collection-elements?noredirect=1#comment112135185_63415198

Comment: I asked "this, that or something else", saying "yes" to that doesnt really help.

Comment: I am expecting response something like Employee filteredEobj = Employee(1,"abc",10001,
                    Arrays.asList(new Address("ad1","ad2","tel","40001"));

Comment: Could you please [edit] your question?

Comment: To clarify, you have a single employee, not multiple? And want to extract 40001 addresses out of him and construct a new employee based on that? Not changing the original employee? What if there are multiple 40001 addresses? What if there is none?

Comment: Simple and direct : Employee employeeWith40001= new Employee(1,"abc",10001,eObj.getAddrs().stream().filter(a->a.getPin().equals("40001")).collect(Collectors.toList()));
  
  System.out.println("Employee : "+employeeWith40001);

Answer (score 3):

### Stream

Assuming you have corresponding getters and are asking for a stream variant:

```
Address address = eObj.getAddresses()
    .stream()
    .map(Employee::getAddress)
    .anyMatch(a -> a.getPostCode().equals("40001"))
    .orThrow(); // Whatever logic you want in case not found

Employee filteredEObj = new Employee(eObj.getFoo(), eObj.getBar() , eObj.getBaz(), List.of(address)); // i dont really know what those parameters are supposed to be
```

---

### Traditional loop

And here the more traditional approach:

```
Address matchAddress = null;
for (Address address : eObj.getAddresses()) {
    if (address.getPostCode().equals("40001")) {
        matchAddress = address;
        break;
    }
}

if (matchAddress == null) {
    // TODO case not found ...
}

Employee filteredEObj = new Employee(eObj.getFoo(), eObj.getBar() , eObj.getBaz(), List.of(matchAddress));
```

---

### Just streams

And finally a variant that uses streams all the way:

```
Employee filteredEObj = eObj.getAddresses()
    .stream()
    .map(Employee::getAddress)
    .filter(a -> a.getPostCode().equals("40001"))
    .limit(1)
    .map(a -> new Employee(eObj.getFoo(), eObj.getBar() , eObj.getBaz(), List.of(a));
    .findAny()
    .orThrow(); // Whatever logic you want in case not found
```

---

### Multiple matches

In case you are interested in all matching addresses and not just one, you can simple collect into a list. For example:

```
List<Address> addresses = eObj.getAddresses()
    .stream()
    .map(Employee::getAddress)
    .filter(a -> a.getPostCode().equals("40001"))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());

// List is empty in case no matches

Employee filteredEObj = new Employee(eObj.getFoo(), eObj.getBar() , eObj.getBaz(), addresses);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can filter then addresses then create employee using data of new addresses.

```
List<Address> filterdAddresses = eObj.getAdresses()
                            .stream()
                            .filter(a -> a.getPin().equals("40001"))
                            .collect(Collectors.toList());

Employee filteredEObj = new Employee(eObj.getId(), eObj.getName() , eObj.getEmpId(), filterdAddresses);
```

*Note:* I am assuming the getters for `Employee` as you don't show the class yet

Comment: https://www.baeldung.com/java-streams-find-list-items This is the best solution I found.

Answer (score 0):

```
List<Employee> employees = empObjs.stream()
                                   .filter(e -> ("40001").equals(e.getPin())
                                   .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Reading OPs comments I have the feeling that he has a single employee and wants to construct a new employee out of that, not filtering a list of employees.